# PopulatingTextBoxes with Items from ListBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a ListBox1 and a series of TextBoxes from TextBox9 onwards.I can populate the ListBox1 with Items(in sequence).I am trying to transfer those items to TextBoxes in the same order(one item for one TextBox).
I tried this code:

```
      Dim x As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex   




      For x =  0 To 50  




      For Each ListBoxItem In ListBox1.Items   




      ListBox1.SelectedItem = "TextBox" & (x+9) & ".Text"




      Next   




      Next x
```

The code compiles but nothing happens when i click the button.Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance
Venkatraman

Answer (score 0):

One way among others could be using the FrameworkElement.FindName() method, see also the following sample.

FWIW, in WPF using the MVVM pattern makes much more sense than one might expect at first glance, where usually a `ViewModel` would provide UI content among other things, and you usually would not want to do too much in the `View`'s code-behind.

Sample.XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
        <ListBox x:Name="l1"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="t1"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="t2"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="t3"/>
        <Button Content="Test" Height="25" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Sample.VB:

```
Class MainWindow

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        l1.Items.Add("Item1")
        l1.Items.Add("Item2")
        l1.Items.Add("Item3")
        l1.Items.Add("Item4")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim s As String
        For Each item As String In l1.Items
            i = i + 1
            s = String.Format("t{0}", i)
            Dim control = Me.FindName(s)
            If TypeOf control Is TextBox Then
                control.Text = item
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hello Stefan,Thanks for your quick response.Your code compiles but i am not able to populate my textboxxes with thwe listbox items.There is no mention of specfic TextBox inyour code.How should i mention it.?A little nudge here will propably see me through.

Comment: Dear Stefan,Thanks a lot.Your code compiles,but i am not able to populate my TextBoxes with ListBox items.Unless there is a specific mention of TextBox names ,how they can get filled up.A little further help here will solve my problem.

Comment: Hi, the TextBox names in the sample are "t1", "t2", "t3". And the `s = String.Format("t{0}", i)` line is the one in Button_Click() that produces the name string. So you could rename the controls in the Xaml as well as modify that line. I'm not sure if I understood your comments though, how does the sample not do what you want when you run it and click the "Test" button?

Comment: Now i understood you.I shall try again and comeback to you tomorrow.Now it is 9.00 PM for me.Thanks Stefan.

Comment: I have reached up to this stage.I am left with one error.  error BC30506: Handle
s clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one o
f its base types.

Comment: I got it.You are an Angel Stefan.Tomorrow in leisure i shall achieve what i want.I shall come back to you with all details.Mine is a bigger project.You have helped after i toiled for 3 days X 8 hrs.I am extremely thankfull to you.God bless you. Venkatraman